# Get data from one website and show it in another website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, flash, iframe

Our client has two websites and they share one common section, he wants us to pick data on the fly from one website and display it as it is in the other website, excluding the header and footer. I tried using an `iframe` but the page contains Flash and it does not show the Flash content in the child website. Using an `iframe` I was able to show the entire website (Flash didn't load) but I don't want the header and footer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note : We don't have database or code access to the parent web site from where we are picking the data.

Comment: You could try something like http://hackaday.com/2012/12/10/web-scraping-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Parse(on server-side) from first site & display this on second site without header and footer?

Comment: you may find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Answer (score 0):

didn't quite understand your Note..
Considering you can add some code to both sites and you want to show only part of the site -

assume you have siteA and siteB here is a simple solution:
siteA can open an iframe that hosts siteB with a url param like ?sendSiteA=true
in the js of siteB, when parsing this param you will have a function that will grab section that you want to show, append it to the body and hide everything else.
this is not the best way to share data, but it will work.

P.S. you can pass the dimensions of the iframe in another url param and adjust the dimentions of rht section in siteB

Comment: I dont have access to the parent Site.

Comment: but the parent site embeds the iframe - it just have to add the params to the url e.x.- http://embedddedSite.com?displayOnlySection=true&width=100&height=100